# Issue with timeouts using bcrypt on AWS lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I'm making a web app using AWS lambda.  Everything is working great and my cold start requests are under 200ms.  Go has absolutely blazing speed.  But there is an issue with user registration and auth.

Computing a bcrypt hash takes 19 seconds with 128 mb of reserved memory.  Increasing the memory does take the request time down but increases the cost per transaction.

For only two of my calls needing the increased space this seems pretty wasteful.  I'm considering making a separate endpoint for just auth.  They share a DB so would not matter to much.

Is there a better way?
Different auth scheme?
Different infrastructure?

Comment: It depends on so many things. Which implementation of bcrypt? (golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt?) What cost are you using? What instance type? Have you tried profiling to make sure it's bcrypt spending all this time?

Comment: I am using golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt.  What would you recommend as the minimum cost to use for safety?  Looks like the census is a minimum of 4.  Currently using 10.

Comment: 10 is the default cost. Try running the bcrypt benchmark on your instance (you still haven't told us which type you're using). For reference, I'm getting about 20 ops/s (both hashing and hashing+verification with default cost of 10) on a m3.large. Allocation statistics show 5KB per op. Did you profile your code? I seriously doubt this is bcrypt.

Comment: I'm not using an elastic compute (ec2) this is a lambda processing function.  Server less architecture.  I'm not sure on the number of CPU's allocated to lambda processing but I have a view into the available memory.  There is 128mb allocated to my function as a default.  Since bcrypt is memory intensive it just takes a long time to process.  I'm going to start testing cost functions with different memory allocations and see if I can get processing under one second.

Comment: oops, I missed the lambda part. Maybe try with higher memory allocations and benchmark a few runs, running just the auth endpoints with higher ram might be reasonable. If it's that bad though, I would consider ditching lambda.

Comment: Lambda is so cheap. Use 1536MB and see if the performance is good enough.